# WCF RIA Services Authorization

Tags: wcf, authorization, roles, wcf-ria-services

Assume we have two groups "Admins" and "Users". Admins are able to use any operation available in the service but the users can only use some of them.

Should I add the "Admins" group to every single operation or if I just write it on top of the class will do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple RequiresRole attributes are combined with an AND while multiple roles passed to a single attribute are OR'd. In your case, you'll want to OR the attributes ("User" or "Admin") so you'll have to apply "Admin" to every single method.

// "Admin" && "User", equivalent to using a class attribute for "Admin"

[RequiresRole("Admin"), RequiresRole("User")]

// "Admin" || "User"

[RequiresRole("Admin", "User")]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I assign every user whether he/she is an admin or not, I won't have to apply the user role attribute to every operation. Right?

Comment: Well... I don't think so. You might be able to apply "User" at the DomainService level (you must be a User to access anything) and then selectively apply "Admin" on individual operations (you must be a User and an Admin to use those methods). I don't think there's a good way to say "you must be an Admin to use these methods unless I specify something else".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unfortunately you have to set the roles on every method. Alternatively you can use [saf-framework](http://qualityofdata.com/category/saf-simple-authorization-framework/) to implement acces based authorization.

Otherwise, I would suggest you overwrite the BeforeSubmit() method of you domain service, and check access for your objects there to avoid excessive attributes on each method.

For example you may want to change your access strategy and you don't want to go through every single method and do that.